Non trivial open sets of a connected hausdorff space are not compact.
I realize that open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under standard topology are not compact. I was then wondering under what conditions can a topology have this be true in general.
I then hypothesize that given a topological space $X$ which is Hausdorff and connected, non trivial open sets(open sets that are not $\varnothing$ and $X$) are not compact and I have a proof which someone can check.
Take a non trivial open set $A\subset X$. Knowing that $X$ is a connected space, every non trivial open set cannot be closed and thus $A$ is not closed. Given that compact sets in Hausdorff spaces must be closed we know $A$ is not compact. Would this proof be correct?
A follow up question is whether there are topological spaces with weaker conditions(than Hausdorff) that can guarantee non trivial open sets to be non compact?

Your proof is correct.

About your second question: this also holds for KC spaces ($:\Leftrightarrow$ compact sets are closed). Of course, every Hausdorff space is KC, but not vice versa.

Oh interesting, I'll check it out.
